# Axis2 runtime location incorrect

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis

I'm trying to set up the Axis2 runtime location on eclipse. I go to window - preferences - web services - Axis2 preferences and then I locate the runtime location to:

```
\Downloads\Software\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\bin
```

but then I receive this error

```
Error occurred while loading Axis2 runtime. Select the correct Axis2 runtime folder.
```

Any help?

**EDIT: I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)**

Here are the web tools I have installed. I also have Axis2 Tools installed but it got cut of from the screen shot [image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526548/how-to-add-apache-axis2-web-service-runtime-to-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you think, try:

`\Downloads\Software\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\`